# How to pivot a pandas dataframe such that unique values across multiple columns become new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of the form:

**df**

```
    col_1      col_2      col_3      col_4
ID
1     A          B          C          A
2     B          D
3     A          C          B

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['A','B','A'], 'col_2':['B','D','C'], 'col_3':['C',np.NaN,'B'], 'col_4':['A', np.NaN, np.NaN]}, index=[1,2,3])
```

Note that the values repeated across the columns are not accidental- they refer to the same entities (A in col_1 is the same as A in col_4, for instance). I am trying to pivot the values of this dataframe so that these unique values become the new columns. For instance, **df** would become:

**new_df**

```
      A      B      C      D
ID
1     2      1      1      0
2     1      0      0      1
3     1      1      1      0
```

The new values represent counts. I have tried [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) but it doesn't give me what I want. What is the most intuitive way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you add the code to create the dataframe

Comment: @DanielMesejo done!

Comment: I believe @W-B answer solves your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC using `stack` with `str.get_dummies`

```
df.stack().loc[lambda x : x!=''].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
    A  B  C  D
ID            
1   2  1  1  0
2   0  1  0  1
3   1  1  1  0
```